# On Hurwitz Square (r, s, t)-Identities examples

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, spherical-geometry

By (r, s, t)-identity I mean any sort of such identity:
$$ 
(x_1^2+\ldots + x_r^2)(y_1^2+\ldots +y_s^2)=(z_1(x,y)^2+\ldots + z_t(x,y)^2),
$$
where $z_i(x,y)$ is a polynomial for every $i$.

See this for some further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_problem

I can't find in the web any non-standard examples of such identities like Adem's example of (3,5,7)-identity or some others for small r, s and t. Can anyone provide several such expressions?

Comment: you want Shapiro, *Compositions of Quadratic Forms*  http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b13484096~S1   along with Lam http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b16142439~S1

Comment: Apparently what you really want is Rajwade, *Squares*  http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14952300~S1  I have a copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From pages 137-138 of [Rajwade](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14952300~S1), "Notes on Chapter 10"

the Hurwitz-Radon theorem gives
$$  (2,2,2), \; (4,4,4), \; (8,8,8), \; (9,16,16), \; (10,32,32), \ldots  $$

K. Y. Lam found $(10,10,16)$ in 1966.

In 1975, Adem found
$$  (3,5,7), \; (10,10,16), \; (12,12,28), \; (13,13,28), \; (17,18,32), \ldots  $$

In 1982, Yuzvinski found
$$   (10,10,16), \; (12,20,32), \; (14,40,64), \ldots  $$

He recommends a 1989 survey article by Shapiro called *Products of Sums of Squares*

https://people.math.osu.edu/shapiro.6/lec1.pdf

https://people.math.osu.edu/shapiro.6/lec2.pdf

https://people.math.osu.edu/shapiro.6/lec3.pdf